# How to calculate this integral?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Define
$$F=(x^2+y-4,3xy,2xz+z^2)$$

Compute the integral of Curl F over the surface $x^2+y^2+z^2=16, z\geq 0$

Comment: This problem has Stokes' theorem written all over it.

Comment: @ZettaSuro: Surely you meant Stokes' theorem. I agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Stokes' theorem](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/StokesTheorem.aspx):

$$\iint_S\nabla \times \vec{F}\cdot\hat{n}dS$$

can be done over the "lid" of the surface, so just integrate over the disk at the bottom of the half-sphere, whose surface normal is $\hat{n}=\langle 0,0,1 \rangle$. This greatly simplifies the issue of having to take the curl of $\vec{F}$, because now all you need to consider is the z component.

The integral becomes:

$$\iint_S(3y-1)dA$$

where $S$ is the disk of radius $4$ centered at the origin.